# Cmake example for pi-pico

Tags: pi-4, pi-pico

Does anyone have an example of a cmake config for pi-pico project?

Comment: It sounds like you want to know 1) How to compile a pi-pico project. 2) How to implement that process using cmake.  If you already know #1 and you have used cmake before, then it should not be too hard to come up with a more specific question.  If you haven't used cmake before, then you need to begin learning that and ask (specific) questions as necessary.  Alternately, you could ask for a simple example of a pi-cpio project, which is how I've edited this...

Comment: ...I recommend you add something more specific to that, such as showing what you've tried and indicate specifically and explicitly points where it doesn't work or you are not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation has lots of cmake examples. Chapter 3 of the 'Getting started with pico' has one.

There are lots more examples in the documentation.

https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/pico/getting-started-with-pico.pdf

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/rp2040/getting-started/